# How to access a function in the root class in kivy without any button press event?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to access a function that is defined inside the root class without a button press event. But i am getting an error when i tried to execute the following code.

I am a novice in kivy app development

**lesson1.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class Screen1(Screen):
    user_name = ObjectProperty(None)
    user_age = ObjectProperty(None)

class Screen2(Screen):
    display = ObjectProperty(None)

    def validate(self):
        text = "Name : {} Age: {}".format(Screen1.user_name.text, Screen2.user_age.text)
        self.display.text = text

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("Design.kv")

class QuestionnaireApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    QuestionnaireApp().run()
```

**Design.py**

```
WindowManager:
    Screen1
    Screen2

<Screen1>:
    name: "login"
    user_name: name
    user_age: age

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Name"
            TextInput:
                id: name
                multiline: False
            Label:
                text: "Age"
            TextInput:
                id: age
                multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_release:"question"

<Screen2>:
    name: "question"
    display: display
    TextInput:
        id: display
    root.validate()
```

**error message**

```
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "C:\Users\pavan m sunder\virtual environments\android\Design.kv", line 33:
 ...
      31:    TextInput:
      32:        id: display
 >>   33:    root.validate()
 ...
 Invalid class name
```

Comment: You have to properly indent the root.validate() function.

Comment: i tried indenting properly..but still getting errors..kindly help

Comment: You need some kind of action to call your function, but you say you don't want a button press. When do you want `root.validate` to be called? When the user types something?

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax but you will need to define the root.object

```
TextInput:
    id: display
    on_text_validate: root.yourobject
```

Comment: I never found an answer in the end. Eventually I decided being stuck in a kivy loop was to restrictive and removed it from my program.